# Jquery: GIF fails to appear when hover over

Tags: jquery, html5-video, z-index

A print-screen to show how it looks like: http://i50.tinypic.com/24nl15w.png

What I'm trying to archieve is that when the user hovers over one of the buttons a hidden div which contains a GIF of the eye blinking will appear above the video. The problem is that nothing happens at all, and how do I select multiple buttons for the same GIF to appear? Thanks in advance :)

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
      <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/global.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Skranji">
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#apDiv1").hover(
              function () {
               $("#gif").show().attr('src', image.src);
               $('#gif').css('z-index','999999');
               $('#videoplayer').css('z-index','999');
              },

              function(){
               $("#gif").hide();
            });
      </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="center">
            <ul id="ca-menu">
                                <div id="apDiv1">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="../designcompany/index.html">
                                        <span class="ca-icon">Mode</span>
                                        </a>                    
                                    </li>
                                </div>
                                 <div id="apDiv2">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="../designcompany/index.html">
                                        <span class="ca-icon">Mode</span>
                                        </a>                    
                                    </li>
                                </div>
                                 <div id="apDiv3">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="../designcompany/index.html">
                                        <span class="ca-icon">Mode</span>
                                        </a>                    
                                    </li>
                                </div>
                                 <div id="apDiv4">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="../designcompany/index.html">
                                        <span class="ca-icon">Mode</span>
                                        </a>                    
                                    </li>
                                </div>
                                 <div id="apDiv5">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="../designcompany/index.html">
                                        <span class="ca-icon">Mode</span>
                                        </a>                    
                                    </li>
                                </div>
                                 <div id="apDiv6">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="../designcompany/index.html">
                                        <span class="ca-icon">Mode</span>
                                        </a>                    
                                    </li>
                                </div>
                            </ul>

                            <div id="w">
                                <img id="gif" src="eye.gif" style="display: none; position: absolute; top:0; left:0;"/>
                                    <div id="videoplayer">
                                        <center>
                                            <video id="intro" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" autobuffer="autobuffer" muted="muted" width="1024" height="400">
                                            <source src="./media/eye.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                                            </video>
                                        </center>   
                                    </div>
                            </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are lacking a

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*...your stuff goes here...*/
});
```

which should wrap what jQuery you currently have.
That way jQuery will wait till your DOM is fully read by your browser and `ready` to be manipulated.

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

or you can use a helpful shorthand to `document.ready` like:

```
$(function(){ // Now DocumentObjectModel is ready 
    /* your stuff in here */
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works now!!! But how do I select all the div button on this line: $("#apDiv1").hover(

Comment: You mean apDiv 1- 6? That would be: $('ca-menu > div') but it might be better to give them all a class, and do $('.yourClass')

Comment: @Watson, NO cause if you use `$('#ca-menu > div')` will also take the `#w` which is not needed. To achieve that goal use `starts-with` selector like: `$('id^=[apDiv]').hover(function(){`

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code and it runs [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N5xfK/1/)
I would check console to see if there is any Links broke

```
$(function(){
  $("#apDiv1").hover(
          function () {
           $("#gif").show().attr('src', image.src);
           $('#gif').css('z-index','999999');
           $('#videoplayer').css('z-index','999');
          },

          function(){
           $("#gif").hide();
        });
});
```